# Can SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services be configured via CMD and a Config file?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering if I can use some command line command and a config file to setup my Reporting Services after I have installed it.  You can do that to install SQL Server so I'm hoping for something that will allow me to have a set config file and then I can quickly do it for a computer/ multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the management console? Its possible using the bat to command the start and stop of the service:
I do not use this process but theoretically this would work:

INSTALL

```
sc create SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
binpath= "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ReportingServicesService.exe"
net start SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
PAUSE
```

STOP

> net stop SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
>       PAUSE

START

```
net start SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
PAUSE
```

UNINSTALL

```
net stop SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
sc delete SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
```

As for parameters and other directives, I do not have that list.

Comment: Btw, all the parameters used reporting services are defined in the *.config files found in the bin folder of ssrs. You could update these files and then restart the service to pick up the new values.